# JQuery: Image appear by mouse move?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a image appear on my site when the mouse moves. It can appear to be a stupid thing to do, but it's really important that when the page loads the image is not yet visible.

My HTML is like this:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="page-container">
        <div>
          <a id="entrar" href="_pt/log_in.html"><img src="_assets/entrar.jpg" alt="entrar"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
<script src="_js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="_js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.js"></script>
<script src="_js/exp.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

In my CSS i'm making the image not visible

```
#entrar {
    display: none;
}
```

And in my Javascript:

```
function PrepareHandlers() {
    $(".page-container").mousemove(function(){
        $("a#entrar").css("display", "inline"); 
    });
}
...
window.onload = function(){
    ....
    PrepareHandlers();
}
```

Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong plz. Thanks

Comment: It would help to create a jsfiddle showing the problem.  At a glance you might try usuing [jquery ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) instead of window.onload.

Comment: It's working for me. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/vctA3/). Try putting some content inside the `.page-container` and then `mousemove`ing over that

Comment: Just curious, why not display `block` instead of `inline`? Since you are wrapping the a tag in block elements anyway. Also, it will help to set the height and width of the image. Are you doing that already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare this in your source file , not inside a function !

```
 $(document).ready( function(){
    $(".page-container").mousemove(function(){
        $("a#entrar").css("display", "inline"); 
    });
})
```

Comment: why did you give this a correct answer then ? does it work or not ?

Comment: My mistake, sorry. I forgot to save before testing xD It worked, thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

It appears likely the page container is not taking up any space, and therefore it never receives a mousemove event.  Here is an easy CSS fix to test this theory:

```
body { position : absolute; top :0; bottom : 0; left : 0; right: 0;} 
.page-container { width : 100%; height : 100%; background-color : #ddd; }
```

[Check out this solution.](http://jsfiddle.net/DB93Q/)

You should preload the image to minimize or avoid an annoying/confusing lag like so:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = '//your/url/to/image';
```

Comment: Tried the alteration to the CSS and still doens't work

Comment: Did you check out the example fiddle?  The code there works fine.